# Type 'Observable<{ product: null; error: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ProductResolved>'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have following *IProduct* and *ProductResolved* interfaces

```
export interface IProduct {
  id: number;
  productName: string;
  productCode: string;
  category: string;
  tags?: string[];
  releaseDate: string;
  price: number;
  description: string;
  starRating: number;
  imageUrl: string;
}

export interface ProductResolved {
 product: IProduct;
 error?: any;
}
```

I am trying to used it in *ProductResolver* as follows

```
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
    import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
    import { ProductResolved } from "./product";
    import { ProductService } from "./product.service";
    
    @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ProductResolver implements Resolve<ProductResolved> {
    
        constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }
    
        resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<ProductResolved> {
            const id = route.paramMap.get('id');
            if (isNaN(+!id)) {
                const message = `Product id was not a number: ${id}`;
                console.error(message);
                return of({product : null,error:message}); //error here
            }
            return of(); //just for example i have return of() here I will change it later
        } 
    }
```

while I return (in above code)

```
return of({product : null,error:message}); //error here
```

it gives an error as

> Type 'Observable<{ product: null; error: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
> Type '{ product: null; error: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ProductResolved'.
> Types of property 'product' are incompatible.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'IProduct'.ts(2322)

**Note :-**
above code seems to be working on typescript version "~3.5.3" but it gives an error on typescript version "~4.3.2"

**Question :-**

1. Is there any changes in latest typescript version("~4.3.2") related to above code?
2. What are best practices to handle above scenario according to new typescript standard?(if there are any changes related to that)?

Comment: try changing the type property of product. `product: IProduct | null`

Answer (score 1):

There are three options to resolve this issue:

- modify property product as optional:
  More information you can find [here](https://exploringjs.com/tackling-ts/ch_typing-objects.html#optional-properties-interfaces)

  ```
  export interface ProductResolved {
        product?: IProduct;
        error?: any;
       }
  ```
- modify product property which could be IProduct or null:

  ```
  export interface ProductResolved {
        product: IProduct | null;
        error?: any;
       }
  ```
- modify product property as any:

  ```
  export interface ProductResolved {
        product: any;
        error?: any;
       }
  ```
- using type assertions as:

  of({product: null, error: message} as IProduct)

More information you can find [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with {} instead of null.
If that didnt work, just give product?: IProduct